# Post to Django's definition from Advanced Rest Client

Tags: python, django, rest, post, advanced-rest-client

Posting values from Advanced Rest client to Django's definition returns "Forbidden(403)" alert [image]

looks like CSRF token is missing in the header, What can be done to get rid of this issue? Below is my definition to receive the POST values

```
def saveToDb(request):
c = {}
c.update(csrf(request))
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form_unique_id = form.cleaned_data['form_id']
        form_meta_data = form.cleaned_data['form_content']
        meta_data = FormMetaData.objects.create(
            form_id=form_unique_id,
            form_content=form_meta_data
        )
        meta_data.save()
        result = FormMetaData.objects.all()
    return render(request, "form_saved.html", {'result': result})
```

There is no issue in the definition as it works well with form input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Post to Django From Advanced Rest Client with CSRF Token:**
Set CSRF Token for the key *"X-CSRFToken"* in the Header Section, add the key-value pairs in the body section, Select the Content type as *"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"* and click the Send Button

**Post to Django from Advanced Rest Client without CSRF Token:** Add the key-value pairs in the body section, Select the Content type as *"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"* and click the Send Button. 
**Note:**
Please make sure to set *"@csrf_exempt"* for the definition to which you post values

as shown below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to give {% csrf_token %} in your html;

```
<html>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: I know that, I'm asking How can I post it from a rest Client? Pl get my question

Comment: then add to your question the related code that doesn't work please